# unable to maintain values in lwc wizard

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have this below code where it is wizard like steps. The problem here is when i am trying to move next and go back again to previous step, I am loosing the values and fields are having empty values.

How to retain the values in the entire process , even if i move forward and previous

HTML

```html
    <template>
        <lightning-progress-indicator current-step={currentStep} type="base" variant="base">
            <lightning-progress-step label="Step 1" value="1" onclick={handleOnStepClick}></lightning-progress-step>
            <lightning-progress-step label="Step 2" value="2" onclick={handleOnStepClick}></lightning-progress-step>
            <lightning-progress-step label="Step 3" value="3" onclick={handleOnStepClick}></lightning-progress-step>
        </lightning-progress-indicator>
    
        <template if:true={isStepOne}>
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Opportunity">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId">
                </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Name">
                </lightning-input-field>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </template>
        <template if:true={isStepTwo}>
            <div>
                Step 2
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:true={isStepThree}>
            <div>
                Step 3
            </div>
        </template>
    
        <template if:true={isEnablePrev}>
            <lightning-button variant="base" label="Back" onclick={handlePrev}></lightning-button>
        </template>
    
        <template if:true={isEnableNext}>
            <lightning-button label="Next" variant="brand" onclick={handleNext}></lightning-button>
        </template>
        <template if:true={isEnableFinish}>
            <lightning-button label="Finish" variant="brand" onclick={handleFinish}></lightning-button>
        </template>
    </template>
```

JS

```js
    import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
    
    export default class Wizardtest extends LightningElement {
        @track currentStep = '1';
     
        handleOnStepClick(event) {
            this.currentStep = event.target.value;
        }
     
        get isStepOne() {
            return this.currentStep === "1";
        }
     
        get isStepTwo() {
            return this.currentStep === "2";
        }
     
        get isStepThree() {
            return this.currentStep === "3";
        }
     
        get isEnableNext() {
            return this.currentStep != "3";
        }
     
        get isEnablePrev() {
            return this.currentStep != "1";
        }
     
        get isEnableFinish() {
            return this.currentStep === "3";
        }
     
        handleNext(){
            if(this.currentStep == "1"){
                this.currentStep = "2";
            }
            else if(this.currentStep = "2"){
                this.currentStep = "3";
            }
        }
     
        handlePrev(){
            if(this.currentStep == "3"){
                this.currentStep = "2";
            }
            else if(this.currentStep = "2"){
                this.currentStep = "1";
            }
        }
     
        handleFinish(){
     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi glls.. used apex.. can u give me an example for browser storage..

Comment: i linked the documentation for the different available browser storage patterns and included a snippet, its pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use on of several strategies:

- [client side storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage)
- store on the SF platform and get with apex

I usually tend to use sessionstorage or localstorage for these types of variables.

samples can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), for storage api's:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('bgcolor')) {
  populateStorage();
} else {
  setStyles();
}

function populateStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', document.getElementById('bgcolor').value);
  localStorage.setItem('font', document.getElementById('font').value);
  localStorage.setItem('image', document.getElementById('image').value);

  setStyles();
}

function setStyles() {
  var currentColor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
  var currentFont = localStorage.getItem('font');
  var currentImage = localStorage.getItem('image');
  //do something with current* values fetched from localstorage
}
```